# How to solve the spam outgoing emails from a VPS?

Tags: email, vps, spam

I bought a new VPS and using WHM i created a cpanel account.
After doing some research about why are the emails were going on spam
without any reasons and by this i mean :

```
 1. No blacklisted IP,
 2. No blacklisted hostname,
 3. Normal emails with only text, not html,
 4. SPF, DKIM and PTR records configured .
```

If there is any other reasons for this please help me .